# IE8 not outlining textbox

Tags: html, css

In IE8 when I set the border of my input fields like that:

```
input {
  border: 0;
}
```

There is no border around the input fields like desired, but I would like an standard outline like in Chrome or Safari whenever the focus is on an input. Now, I could add a border via pseudo class `:focus`, but I do not want that pseudo class apply to browsers that already have a standard outline.

**How can I accomplish that?**

EDIT: I just found out that `:focus` is not working in IE8. I have to add a DOCTYPE to get it working.

Comment: Please explain the downvote!? This is a legitimate issue to me.

Comment: You should always add a DOCTYPE. Only so the browser may guess correctly what you are intending

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To target ie8 specifically you can use [this method](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

Add an ie8 class to your html tag and inherit from that.

On your html tag

```
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
```

Your css

```
.ie8 input:focus {
  //your styles
}
```

Comment: Looks like I have to go with those ugly conditional tags, haven´t I?

Comment: Afraid so, but those tags are a lifesaver. IE8 is generally quite good, but you can use the same method for dealing with ie6/ie7. It will save you masses of time.

Comment: Yeah, guess so. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

You can include the style in a conditional CSS stylesheet:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then in that external stylesheet, include your CSS like:

```
input:focus { border: 1px solid golden; }
```

`focus` should work in IE8. Add the `doctype` and see.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that with the Doctype on W3Schools